# import csv utf8 to phpmyadmin [bug]

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin(Version : 4.6.4) as a platform to import CSV encoded with UTF-8 to database. I am able to import the data, but with no idea why is the first two character of at first-column first-row went missing and this happens every time i import a CSV.

raw: A1610011111-001,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,--

This is what the data supposed to be -> (A1)
[CSV data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TC0S.png)

This is the imported data (A1 went missing)->[imported data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb78H.jpg)

If the data is more than one row, the result will be same(only 1st two character went missing)

I am not sure what is the problem and what is the solution. Please give me a hand on this.

Comment: show the text representation of the import (so we can cut and paste it to test). Show us the source code. Show us the table schema. This question cannot be answered like the above. See **Section2 / What does Show your Schema Mean?** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) to help us to help you

Comment: What type is the first column? Is it an int?

Comment: @Pekka웃 is not a in , it is a varchar. and by the way i am using if i am using phpMyAdmin - 2.10.3 the there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well for anyone still searching for an answer, this is what worked for me after numerous tries.

In Excel (365), you can chose between

- save as csv UTF-8 (sperated by comma's)
- save as csv (seperated by delimiter)

As contradictory as it may seem, when I use the first option, I lose my first 2 characters, whereas choosing the 2nd. option I lose nothing.

So saving without the UTF-8 seems to do the trick.